# Как сделать так чтобы ShaderMaterial с transparent не влиял на другие объекты?

Tags: three.js, glsl

По центру круг с градиентом от прозрачного к фиолетовому, но  все объекты(серый фон) под кругом, что имеют transparent: true, становятся тоже прозрачными:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Материал

```
new THREE.ShaderMaterial( {
  uniforms: {
    u_color: { value: new THREE.Color(0xCC00AB) },
    u_radius: { value: 350 },
  },
  vertexShader: shaders.vertex,
  fragmentShader: shaders.fragment,
  transparent: true
}};
```

Vertex:

```
varying vec3 v_position;

void main() {

    vec4 modelViewPosition= modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewPosition;

    v_position = position;

}
```

Fragment:

```
uniform vec3 u_color;
uniform vec2 u_center;
uniform float u_radius;

varying vec4 v_position;

void main(){

    float a = abs( v_position.x ) / u_radius;
    float b = abs( v_position.y ) / u_radius;

    float opacity = 1.0 - sqrt( pow(a, 2.0) + pow(b, 2.0) ) - 0.1;

    gl_FragColor = vec4(u_color, opacity);
}
```

Comment: Переделал. Сначала идут линии не прозрачный над ними серый фон с прозрачностью над ним идет наш градиент, и наш серый фон исчезает в том месте где выводится наш верхний градиент

Comment: Оно и без шейдеров будет работать точно так же, скорее всего. Тут вот похожий вопрос: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11165345/4045502 . А что, если использовать шейдер на плоскости? Что бы радиальный градиент от фиолетового к серому был сразу там.

Comment: @prisoner849 Спасибо) ссылка помогла

Comment: Да не за что :)